# Вопрос по синтаксису Python

Tags: python

```
def big_lists(tag):
    return len(tag.contents) > 20 and tag.name == 'ul'
len(soup.find_all(big_lists))
# 13
```

`soup.find_all()` выдает все теги страницы.

1. А каким образом `find_all` передает их всех в качестве аргумента функции `big_lists`?
2. Если предположить что программа выполняется справа налево, о почему `big_lists` не кричит

> `missing 1 argument, 0 given ?`

3. Глупый вопрос,но почему `soup.find_all(big_lists))`, а не `soup.find_all(big_lists()))`
4. Где-то можно почитать подробнее  про такие "вложения"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_all` - функция высшего порядка. Она принимает функцию в качестве аргумента и вызывает ее столько раз, сколько потребуется, каждый раз передавая ей один аргумент.

> почему `big_lists` не кричит `missing 1 argument, 0 given`?

потому, что ее никто не вызывает без аргументов

> почему `soup.find_all(big_lists))`, а не `soup.find_all(big_lists()))`

потому, что тогда `big_lists` была бы вызвана не в том месте и не с теми параметрами

пример простой функции высшего порядка

```
def higher_order(f):
    for x in range(3):
        print(f(x))
```

```
>>> higher_order(float)
0.0
1.0
2.0
>>> higher_order(hex)
0x0
0x1
0x2
>>> higher_order(lambda x: x * 5)
0
5
10
>>> higher_order(range)
range(0, 0)
range(0, 1)
range(0, 2)
```

Comment: понятно, но разве в find_all есть параметр для функции?  
find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs)

Comment: Функция передается в параметр `name`, судя по всему, API различает аргумент по типу, и если это функция - использует в качестве предиката.

Comment: разработчики хорошо продумали библиотеку))